# Change HTML files and stylesheet in downloaded cayman theme

Tags: html, yaml, webstorm, github-pages

So I cloned the cayman theme from the jekyll cayman repo for GitHub pages (https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman) locally, and wanted to change things from there in my WebStorm IDE. Unfortunately, I can not change anything in the `default.html` file or the CSS stylesheet. Everything just resets automatically to initial content.

I can change the `config.yml` file, but changes does not appear when I update my page. There are no problems with changing the markdown files.

Screenshot of my working environment:

[image: Screenshot of my working environment]

Is cloning the repo and working from there the wrong way to do things, or is there certain files I can delete that makes the changes I want to do possible?

Comment: What command do you use to run the project in WebStorm IDE?

Comment: I have built an custom way to run it that makes the possibility to live edit things by saving in webstorm. The problem is rather that it resets before I save, and even after I save, meaning I can't even update things before it resets.

Comment: Okay, I am using an older version of jekyll and ruby. So I use `bundle exec jekyll serve` and have no issues refreshing the page. I think you are on the right path. Not sure why you cannot see your changes without looking at your environment

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to the default.html file will render at the bottom of the automatically added initial content.

Example paragraph added:

```
<main id="content" class="main-content" role="main">
  {{ content }}

  <p>Example content added</p>

  <footer class="site-footer">
    {% if site.github.is_project_page %}
      <span class="site-footer-owner"><a href="{{ site.github.repository_url }}">{{ site.github.repository_name }}</a> is maintained by <a href="{{ site.github.owner_url }}">{{ site.github.owner_name }}</a>.</span>
    {% endif %}
    <span class="site-footer-credits">This page was generated by <a href="https://pages.github.com">GitHub Pages</a>.</span>
  </footer>
</main>
```

Displayed in the browser:

[image]

For styling the project there is information in the Cayman documentation [here](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman). Or you could create another import SCSS/SASS file under their `@import 'jekyll-theme-cayman';` to override their stylesheet.

I hope this helps.